# Realistic Outdoor Lighting in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I'm interested in architectural illustration and always find it hard to get a realistic outdoor lighting (shinny/cloudy).
Can you provide settings/tutorials for that?

Comment: This is a QA site, tutorial requests do not really belong here: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials

Answer (score 6):

For quick results you could setup an environment texture in the world properties.  For this examples I used a free example from [hdri-hub](http://www.hdri-hub.com/hdrishop/freesamples/freehdri/item/113-hdr-111-parking-space-free). Note that this only works for stills an animation would look weird.

You can also create your own panorama pictures (with limited quality) with a smartphone or tablet.

[image]

Comment: Why would an animation look weird?

Comment: @gandalf3 Because it would depend on the environment map, when there are objects they don't have a plausible distance due to the 2D 'spheric photo' and wouldn't rotate  as your scene would.

Comment: If you had your own 3D environment I think it would be okay though (if the hdri was only used for the sky), and the lighting would be consistent (i.e. you could use the HDRI only for lighting and make the sky transparent/white/whatever instead)