# How to make the glare coming from strong sunlight?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I want to create more or less realistic light in outdoor scenes. I read this question 
[Lighting for a outdoor scene in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21486/lighting-for-a-outdoor-scene-in-cycles)

The answer says you should set up the sun lamp properly and use environment texture. However,  don't get specular highlights and reflections of the sun. How do you create such things?

This is the sun highlight I mean:

[image]

Comment: If you open the default scene, put a default sun lamp and a glossy object you should be able to see the highlights. Could you be more clear about what the problem is and what have you tried so far? What's your lamp size?

Comment: yeah, I see them (kind of). But I mean really sun highlights like this:

Comment: That kind of glare can be created in the compositor with a glare node;

Comment: It is usually called ["glare"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glare_(vision)). Easiest way to simulate them is to use the glare node during compositing.

Comment: Sortof related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23111/599