# How to add good light to surrounding to get a best result

Tags: light

I wanna know is there any addon to get a perfect result for my model with lighting. Adjusting the lamp here and there and increase and decrease the light not get much good result. I have added HDRI light but yet also not good result i got. Whats the easy way and simple to get good light result. If so addon. I have attached an image with hdri and a gold material[image]

Comment: I bet there isn't any addon to get anything perfect, lighting in particular. Setup it properly with several lamps and environment, and then manage the color to get something aiming to photorealistic.

Comment: [Lighting for a outdoor scene in cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21486/2217) may be helpful for you.

Comment: how much is the bet.......... for there is addon

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't terribly clear, but I'll give you a few hints at the complexity behind such questions.

For one, your scene referred render (assuming you are using Cycles) will range from zero to infinity in terms of values. The viewing transform (see the color management panel) determines how much of this scene you are going to "see" end up in your final render.

So what is "good" then? If we are talking about a photographic "good", then you can't achieve it with the default sRGB mapping of scene values to display referred values. **It is fundamentally impossible** without additional tweaking and bending. This is apparent from the clipped scene values in the upper right of your sample image.

The proper solution to getting a photographic dynamic range is simply to replace or add one of your transforms to properly map your scene referred range down into the display referred range.

For more information, you can peruse the tip of this complex iceberg [over at this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im).

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon for it [Pro-Lighting Studio](https://www.blenderguru.com/product/pro-lighting-studio/).
Although if this is gold material, and You're using HDRI light, then You're doing something wrong, cause it should look way different.