# Lighting Room For Photorealistic look

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to create a bedroom and I thought I'd light the room up. I've added a HDRI but the room looks really artificial. Anyone know where I'm going wrong? Do I need to add light or remove light?[image]

Comment: Do you use Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: I have used Eevee

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to only count on the HDRI, especially if it's an interior scene, it makes no sense as you always have a source for your lights in a room (the windows or the lamps). So you should use lights imho. If you really count on the HDRI, at least enable the Ambient Occlusion option in the Properties panel > Render, and play with the settings. Also, for your light, make sure that the Shadow option is enabled (and Contact Shadow as well). The shadows quality are tweakable in the Render panel > Shadows.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5318 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123164

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make 100% photorealistic renders with Eevee. So if you want an photorealistic result, you should use Cycles. It is a lot slower thain Eevee, but it is the only way to get a photorealistic result. There are a lot of videos on YouTube, on how to reduce the render time.

If you still want to use Eevee, I would not use an HDRI for an indoor scene.

Comment: What would you use instead of an HDRI with eevee?

Comment: I think would use a sun light.